# In Google Sheets is it possible to grab data from a table and use the filter buttons?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have a spread sheet that i want to use to track production milestones.

The issue I'm having is, I want to be able to sort the data with the filter button and slicers but anytime I use this the data reset to the order of the referenced data on the other sheet and the check boxes end up all over the palce.

Is there a way to grab the data and use the filter buttons and slicers without everything braking

I'm using the =importage finction to get a list of job data, then on another sheet I used the =query function to arrage the data and then added check boxes for each milestone and a script that put the current time into the adjecent column when a checkbox is ticked.

Below is a link to a viewer only copy of the sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18SQZmLIFu5E9cEUhuO2ScIWqkdm_wFIyvGZoSi9nMeA/edit?usp=sharing